# Adding read more toggle 2

Tags: jquery

I am having issues with my "read more" toggle code thats suppose to change to "read less" when clicked.  How do i make this code to only be called for the class that is clicked instead of all the classes. Each of the stories have a read more button using the same class hence each time the read more is clicked for one of the stories, it changes all other "read more" text to "read less". How do i make it change only the one thats clicked.

This is my Jquery code which works fine but is called multiple times on the page. I just need to add something to it:

```
$(".morelink_L3").click(function() {
     $(".morelink_L3 span").html($(".morelink_L3 span").html() == 'Read less' ? 'Read more' : 'Read less');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="story_L3">
Story1 text... Lorem dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
</div>
<span class="morelink_L3" value="True"><span>Read more</span></span>

<div class="story_L3">
Story2 text... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
</div>
<span class="morelink_L3" value="True"><span>Read more</span></span>

<div class="story_L3">
Story3 text... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
</div>
<span class="morelink_L3" value="True"><span>Read more</span></span>
```

(Although this is related to a previous question which is fixed, I had to start a new post because my text here is too long to be added as a comment in the last one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).find("span")` instead of using `$(".morelink_L3 span")`.

Try this

```js
$(function(){
  $(".morelink_L3").click(function() {
     $(this).find("span").html($(this).find("span").html() == 'Read less' ? 'Read more' : 'Read less');
  });
});
```

```css
.morelink_L3{
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="story_L3">
Story1 text... Lorem dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
</div>
<span class="morelink_L3" value="True"><span>Read more</span></span>
<br><br>
<div class="story_L3">
Story2 text... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
</div><br>
<span class="morelink_L3" value="True"><span>Read more</span></span>
<br><br>
<div class="story_L3">
Story3 text... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
</div>
<span class="morelink_L3" value="True"><span>Read more</span></span>
```